# Ensure to get all values of `ConcurrentHashMap` when iterating over it while other threads put elements

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

I have a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) that gets filled with `put` by 8 different Threads. One of the 8 Threads tries to read with a `forEach` consumer. My problem is, that the `ConcurrentHashMap` only has 5-7 entries.

```
map.put(myContent);

...

map.forEach(element -> ... do something);
```

If I add a [`map.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#size--) it for some reason shows all 8 entries

```
map.put(myContent);
map.size();
...
map.forEach(element -> ... do something);
```

Going through the [`ConcurrentHashMap` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) shows that it is not really thread-safe to iterate the map. It is not ensured to get all entries:

> For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries. Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException.

Is it possible to somehow wait or synchronize before I iterate to get absolutly all entries?

Comment: Introducing synchronization kind of ruins the idea of using a `ConcurrentMap`, unless your usage pattern is that the adding threads finish putting things in the map at some point and could signal that it's ready to be read?

Comment: I know, thats why I do not really want to synchronize it. I just dont't understand why the entries are visible if I add the map.size(). That makes no sense to me.

Comment: Why not use a queue?

Comment: Because I realize the Pub/Sub pattern, where sub is the `map.put` and the pub is the `map.forEach`. It actually works well in the live system. If I use it in a chain (my unit test) it fails, because the map does not update its state unless I add the `map.size()` which irritates me.

Comment: or actually its a bench not a unit test.

Comment: There's certainly nothing saying that they're guaranteed to be visible after a call to `size()`, so it's a side effect you shouldn't be relying on in any case. How `CHM` works is well specified, you can't become irritated because you're using it in a way that's clearly not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Kayaman If you could write this as an answere would be nice. I would accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `ConcurrentHashMap.size()` doesn't provide any guarantees about visibility effects, it delegates to the following method which does the actual counting

```
final long sumCount() {
    CounterCell[] as = counterCells; CounterCell a;
    long sum = baseCount;
    if (as != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < as.length; ++i) {
            if ((a = as[i]) != null)
                sum += a.value;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Presumably as a side effect it makes all the elements visible in your code, but that's not something you should rely on (at least unless you understand the inner workings of `ConcurrentHashMap`, I don't).

The purpose of `ConcurrentHashMap` is to provide thread-safe insertion and retrieval, but I suppose getting iteration to work in a reliable way is hard or impossible. I'm not aware of any standard `Maps` that would work as a replacement either, another concurrent map `ConcurrentSkipListMap` also says that its iterators and spliterators are *weakly consistent*.