# Is ConcurrentHashMap's forEach method thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

If want to iterate over all elements in ConcurrentHashMap, is using the `forEach` method thread-safe?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301523/ensure-to-get-all-values-of-concurrenthashmap-when-iterating-over-it-while-oth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by thread-safe.

- If you're okay with other threads being able to modify the map while you're in the middle of a `forEach` call, then yes, it is thread-safe.
- If you want the map to be unmodifiable while `forEach` is in progress such that other threads are blocked or error out if they attempt to modify it then no, it is not.

The [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) says:

> However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access.
>
> ...
>
> Similarly, Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.... Bear in mind that the results of aggregate status methods ... are typically useful only when a map is not undergoing concurrent updates in other threads. Otherwise the results of these methods reflect transient states that may be adequate for monitoring or estimation purposes, but not for program control.

Comment: "Retrieval" operation is not the same as iterating over the values. It means to `get` a value using a key.

Comment: @Deadbeef it is - the warning here applies. When you `put` an entry into that map halfway through iterating it, The CHM impl is free to flip an evil coin and iterate over it, or not, depending on the coinflip. (Evil in the sense that murphy's law will ensure the coin lands heads every time as you develop it and on the test server, and then when you give the demo to the big potential customer, it starts flipping tails just to mess with you). CHM must either include it or not. Contrast to j.u.HM which can crash, throw, include it, not include it, skip 20 keys, or dance a jig.